# Manga where kid is destined to end the world

Tags: story-identification, manga

I can only remember a few things.

- He and his mother live with a vampire
- the MC is interested in another person
- one of the books is about a sports coach who uses a curse to win every game but the main character defeats them.

Answer (score 0):

Might be "[The Chronicles of Nick; Infinity](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/k/sherrilyn-kenyon/chronicles-of-nick-graphic-novel/)" graphic novels by Sherrilyn Kenyon. They're based on the first volume of the "Chronicles of Nick" book series by her.